# Designing a WPF control that has an expandable TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I'm trying to develop a WPF control that has a `TextBlock` in it. This control will be displayed in a `DataTemplate` for an `ItemsControl`. In this control, I want the control by default to have a fixed height (let's say 150 to set a baseline). The `TextBlock` will trim its content based on how many pixels are available. I also have an "Expand" button that I want to have the behavior of expanding that textbox to be the desired height to have all the text display without any trimming.

I have the trimming detection working as long as my TextBlock height is not constrained, based on the code [here](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2010/10/determining-if-textblock-has-been.html). It seems I may have to go down the custom control route and override `Arrange` and `Measure` but I was hoping I could solve this with just XAML.

My ViewModel will have an `IsExpanded` property that the `ToggleTextExpansionCommand` command will toggle when executed. I'm not sure what I should be doing on my `IsExpanded` trigger, though, to make the `TextBlock` expand to take up all the room it needs.

My `DataTemplate` right now looks as follows:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Height="140">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- other rows exist -->
            <RowDefinition Height=*" /> <!-- textblock row -->
        </Grid>

        <!-- other content -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding MyText}" />

        <Button x:Name="ExpanderButton" Command="{Binding ToggleTextExpansionCommand}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="MyTextBlock" Property="Controls:TextBlockServices.IsTextTrimmed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ExpanderButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded}" Value="True">
            <!-- what do I do here?? -->
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: can you not just set the TextBlock Height to Auto in the trigger?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 If I do that then what do I set my Grid height to be? Auto as well? If I have my Grid height set to a value then the TextBlock will be big but it will just have the text cut-off. I also don't know what specifying * as a RowHeight means if the Grid height is Auto.

Comment: I would wrap the button and TextBlock in its own container and bind the Grids height to the ActualHieght of that container, using hardcoded values will make things a lot harder

Comment: Hmm.... that may be tricky since there are a lot more controls apart from these two. But I can go down the path and see how it turns out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided by sa_ddam213. If he updates this question with an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Basically the containing `Grid` that has a height of 140 would have a height set to Auto.